# Check if string contains non-alphanumeric except underscore

Tags: c#, if-statement, alphanumeric

I'm trying to write in if statement that runs if a string contains any non-alpahnumeric character with the exception of an underscore.

This is what I have and I'm trying to figure a simple way to add the exception for underscore but I'm having difficulty. (where key is a string).

```
// Check for non-alphanumerics except underscore
if (!(key.All(char.IsLetterOrDigit)))                                        
{
    validationResult = false;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by _I'm having difficulty_?

Comment: I mean I'm an amateur and I hardly know what I'm doing. I've tried a few things that do work, but I can only make something work if I break it out into heaps of lines. I'd like somebody to help me understand a way to do it in one line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to extend the logic within the `All`:

```
if (!(key.All(c => char.IsLetterOrDigit(c) || c=='_')))
```

Comment: Thanks. That's exactly what I needed. Will remember for next time.